# The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous in creation of model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm in the process of compiling a model. I created the model, but unfortunately I get an error. You can see this below.
Unfortunately, the error message doesn't mean much to me and I can't find any advice that would help me to fix this error.
How can I fix this? I am very happy about your advice, answers and ideas.

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-15a9c8e5145f> in <module>()
     12 
     13 
---> 14 model = get_model(num_users, num_items, latent_dim, dense_layers, reg_layers, reg_mf[0])
     15 #model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=learning_rate), loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
     16 #print(model.summary())

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/embeddings.py in __init__(self, input_dim, output_dim, embeddings_initializer, embeddings_regularizer, activity_regularizer, embeddings_constraint, mask_zero, input_length, **kwargs)
    102       else:
    103         kwargs['input_shape'] = (None,)
--> 104     if input_dim <= 0 or output_dim <= 0:
    105       raise ValueError('Both `input_dim` and `output_dim` should be positive, '
    106                        'found input_dim {} and output_dim {}'.format(

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

**Code:**

```
def get_model(num_users, num_items, latent_dim=8, dense_layers=[64, 32, 16, 8],
              reg_layers=[0, 0, 0, 0], reg_mf=0):

    # input layer
    input_user = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='user_input')
    input_item = Input(shape=(1,), dtype='int32', name='item_input')
    
    # embedding layer
    mf_user_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=num_users, output_dim=latent_dim,
                        name='mf_user_embedding',
                        embeddings_initializer='RandomNormal',
                        embeddings_regularizer=l2(reg_mf), input_length=1)
    mf_item_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=num_items, output_dim=latent_dim,
                        name='mf_item_embedding',
                        embeddings_initializer='RandomNormal',
                        embeddings_regularizer=l2(reg_mf), input_length=1)
    mlp_user_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=num_users, output_dim=int(dense_layers[0]/2),
                         name='mlp_user_embedding',
                         embeddings_initializer='RandomNormal',
                         embeddings_regularizer=l2(reg_layers[0]), 
                         input_length=1)
    mlp_item_embedding = Embedding(input_dim=num_items, output_dim=int(dense_layers[0]/2),
                         name='mlp_item_embedding',
                         embeddings_initializer='RandomNormal',
                         embeddings_regularizer=l2(reg_layers[0]), 
                         input_length=1)

    # MF latent vector
    mf_user_latent = Flatten()(mf_user_embedding(input_user))
    mf_item_latent = Flatten()(mf_item_embedding(input_item))
    mf_cat_latent = Multiply()([mf_user_latent, mf_item_latent])

    # MLP latent vector
    mlp_user_latent = Flatten()(mlp_user_embedding(input_user))
    mlp_item_latent = Flatten()(mlp_item_embedding(input_item))
    mlp_cat_latent = Concatenate()([mlp_user_latent, mlp_item_latent])
    
    mlp_vector = mlp_cat_latent
    
    # build dense layer for model
    for i in range(1,len(dense_layers)):
        layer = Dense(dense_layers[i],
                      activity_regularizer=l2(reg_layers[i]),
                      activation='relu',
                      name='layer%d' % i)
        mlp_vector = layer(mlp_vector)

    predict_layer = Concatenate()([mf_cat_latent, mlp_vector])
    result = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', 
                   kernel_initializer='lecun_uniform',name='result')

    model = Model(inputs=[input_user,input_item], outputs=result(predict_layer))

    return model

model = get_model(num_users, num_items, latent_dim, dense_layers, reg_layers, reg_mf[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

`num_users` or `latent_dim` seem to be NumPy arrays. As you can see in the [docs](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/embedding/), these arguments must be integers.

> input_dim: Integer. Size of the vocabulary, i.e. maximum integer index + 1.

> output_dim: Integer. Dimension of the dense embedding.

In the source code, this condition is evaluated:

```
if input_dim <= 0 or output_dim <= 0:
```

This throws the error you've got when the variables are NumPy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

input_dim = np.array([1, 2, 3])

if input_dim <= 0:
    print('this is going to crash')
```

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: Thanks! My problem was this line `num_users = df["visitorid"].unique()`. Have a nice day! :)